# nextInt() Java input in same line

Tags: java, matrix

I'm doing a matrix solving console software on java.

What I am trying to do is that each "**enter**" key do a space instead of break in other to create a row and so on.

When the user types an INT then press "ENTER" it does a break so it breaks the matrix design.

This is my code so far:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);//.useDelimiter("\\s+");

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("| ");
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("|");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    scanner.close();
    System.out.println("Done");
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `nextInt()` doesn't consume a newline, what is the problem.

Comment: you can't change the behaviour of the enter key, but why not just wait until the user has entered the entire row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this possible, so i will suggest another way:

Instead to use `Enter` and return to the line why you don't write all your values and separate them with a **space** or a specific **delimiter**, so when you finish press enter to return to the next line to scan the next row like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
5 6 7 8 9
```

Then you can get your values like this:

```
String line = scan.nextLine();
String[] row = line.split(" ");
```

Then use the `String[]` to get your int values?

This can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In console mode,  enter is enter : that is a breakline.

To solve your problem, you could do things differently :

- You take a user input without consideration about formatting.
- After  each input you re-display the actual result of the matrix object.
  In this way, you format it as you want, you can even display a special character the position of the next number to fill by the user.

With your actual code it could look like :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);//.useDelimiter("\\s+");

for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
        displayActualMatrix(matrix)
    }
}
scanner.close();
System.out.println("Done");
...

private void displayActualMatrix(int[][] matrix){
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
              // rendering the matrix 
           }
      }
   ...
}
```